# jQuery slideToggle doesn't work with colspan in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, html-table

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#description').show();
    $('#extender').click(function() {
    $('#description').slideToggle("fast");

    });

});  
</script>

 <tr>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td><a href="#" id="extender">link</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="description">
    <td colspan="2" class="desc">This should span two columns but it doesnt bla jaajja</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be a problem might with animating table element.
Workaround for this is to put TD's body into a DIV, and animate a DIV.

In my code I use something like this:

```
       var el = $("TR.post_"+_id+' TD');
       el.wrapInner("<div/>");
       $("TR.post_"+_id+' TD DIV').slideUp('500');
       setTimeout(function(){el.remove()},500);
```